# Change the URL on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I m currently on a page

> www.example123.com/search?error=1

. On page refresh, the page should be loaded with the following url.

> www.example123.com/search

or

> www.example123.com/search?error=

How to do this in js or jQuery? The solution should work in all major browsers.

Comment: Is this your website where you can add js or a random website?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @artm yeah i tried pushstate fucntionality in html5. But it doesnt work in less than IE10.

Comment: @Gsx website that i mentioned above was just an example. I typed randomly since i cant reveal my website.

Comment: If it is your website you can just add js to check if the url matches "www.example123.com/search?error=1" and if so redirect to where you want it to.

Comment: @Gsx how will my js code get invoked on page refresh? Can you explain it more?

Comment: Maybe the search-page should switch templates when it encounters an error, but give normal results when there is no error.  Are you using any kind of templating-framework on the web-site?

Comment: Store the pathname of the page you are on every time and when you open a website check if the stored value is the same as the new pathname.

Answer (score 2):

I did it using unload event. This event will be called when a page is refreshed.

```
$(window).unload(function() {
     var currentURL = window.location.href;
     var index = currentURL.indexOf("?error=");
     if(index > -1) {
         window.location.href = currentURL.substring(0, index);
     }
});
```

Then the page will be refreshed with the new URL.

Let me know if this will not work in any case.

Note: It doesnt work in chrome. How to make it work in chrome?

Answer (score -1):

You can detect if the page has refreshed with a cookie,
and then do something like the following:

```
if(refresh==1){
  if(window.location.href=='http://www.example123.com/search?error=1'){
    window.location.replace = "http://www.example123.com/search";
  }
}
```