# Change the get URL parameter on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form in a popup. User fills the details and submits the form. On form submission, the popup is closed and the user is redirected to the homepage. On submission, a message is displayed on the home screen (whether form submission is success or not). This is done by adding a parameter in the home page url.

When user opens the site, the url will be `..../home`. And the user clicks on the popup button and submitting a form.

On success, the url will be redirected to `..../home?error=0`

On Failure, the url will be redirected to `..../home?error=1`

Based on the error flag value, i display the message on home page.

After this step, if user refreshes the home page, he still gets the form submission message because the error flag is present in the url. But after refresh, i dont want to display the message on home page.

So, i tried to remove/set the error flag on page refresh using the following code.

```
> $(window).unload(function() {
>      var currentURL = window.location.href;
>      var index = currentURL.indexOf("?error=");
>      if(index > -1) {
>          window.location.href = currentURL.substring(0, index);
>      } });
```

It works well in Firefox but not in chrome. Not tested in other browsers. But jQuery unload has been deprecated in 1.8.

How to remove/set the error flag on page refresh? Or is there any other method for not to display the message on home page after page refresh. The solution should work in all major browsers (IE, chrome, firefox. opera, safari)

Note: This is a continuation of [Change the URL on page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085609/change-the-url-on-page-refresh)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a $_SESSION, in that case clear the POST values after displaying the page. The next time the page is loaded the $_SESSION variable will be gone. In sequence:

Form submit > method = $_SESSION

Load home page, check if $_SESSION variable set > display the message

Clear the $_SESSION variable

Reload the page? The post variable is not set so go to the home page without displaying the message

Comment: This won't work, because when the user hit F5, Chrome will propose to resend POST data. You can't unset POST data on server side without using redirects.

Comment: Yes you can, simply set the $_POST['error']="" for example

Comment: This will unset the POST variable for the current process, but if the browser window is refreshed - browser will send back the same data.

Comment: Ah you're right, so instead of POST, he could use SESSION

Comment: Haha, that was in my answer below :D

Comment: Gave u the credit, thank you for educating me too ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this problem on server side instead of client side, for example using $_SESSION flag.

In the code of home put this code at the very beginning(if you are using PHP):

```
<?php
    // If there is an error message to show
    if (isset($_GET['error'])){
        // and we still haven't shown it
        if (empty($_SESSION['error_shown'])){
            $_SESSION['error_shown'] = 1; // set the flag that the message is showing right now
        }else{
            // if we already have shown the error message, unset the flag and redirect to the URL with no message
            unset($_SESSION['error_shown']);
            header('Location: /home');
            die();
        }
    }
?>
... your error messages here with the rest of content
```

The code could has some errors, I haven't tested it, but the idea is clear.

Comment: everytime i refresh the page, a new session is created. I m not able to check the parameter(error_show) value that was set on previous call. It is reset to default value on each request.

Comment: Do you open your session with `session_start()` ?
By the way... I found an error in my answer - I use different names 'error_shown' and 'error_show' - now it is fixed - all is 'error_shown'

Comment: I m using Java. Session is opened by request.getSession()

Comment: Well, I don't know how java works with session, but you could use COOKIES instead, because no sensitive information is involved.

Answer (score 1):

the same problem i've faced and below solution helped me out try this.

to read the url:

```
var url = window.location;
```

to change it:

```
window.location.replace(url);
```

to change and redirect:

```
window.location = url;
```

Comment: There are the steps to change the URL. I have already done it. Tell me the place where i have to put this code to work on page refresh.

Comment: you can do it on dialog close on redirected page. as your error message shows and you click on ok or close then format URL on click.

Answer (score 0):

beforeunload should work fine on Chrome!

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    var currentURL = window.location.href;
    var index = currentURL.indexOf("?error=");
    if(index > -1) {
        window.location.href = currentURL.substring(0, index);
    }
});
```

Comment: Not working in chrome. I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a funcion"

Answer (score 0):

```
`$(window).unload(function() {
    var currentURL = document.location.href;
    var index = currentURL.indexOf("?error=");
    if(index > -1) 
        document.location.href = currentURL.substring(0, index); 
});`
```

Comment: Don't hesitate to provide a bit more info about your answer, the goal is to help the user to solve and understand the cause of its problem

Comment: See question, Saravan.

Comment: It works well in Firefox but not in chrome. Not tested in other browsers. But jQuery unload has been deprecated in 1.8.